# Removing the play button in HTML video

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put a video on my website with a customized button.
I have inserted the video element inside a div element with the ID = myVideo. Also, I created an image element with the ID = btnVideo. My idea is to make this image pause/play the video.

The problem is that the video has a play button on default. When I inspect the element, I see that this button is an SVG element.

I tried to use "myVideo.parentElement.lastChild.style.opacity = 0;" to make the element disappear (myVideo.parentElement.lastChild grabs this SVG element).

It works when the page is loaded, but after I pause the video, it's go back to opacity=1, even if I call this line of code again.

How could I make this element to stay hidden? Setting the opacity to 0 is the best approach?

My Javascript code is

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo").firstChild; 
var btnVid = document.getElementById("btnVideo");


myVideo.parentElement.lastChild.style.opacity = 0


btnVid.addEventListener('click', function playPause(e) {

  if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
  else 
    myVideo.pause();
    console.log(myVideo.parentElement.lastChild.style.opacity)

  myVideo.parentElement.lastChild.style.opacity = 0;
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Why don't you try `display: none` instead of `opacity` 0.

Comment: if the video came with its own button, chances are good that the video has additional functionality to hide/show that button based on play status (ie, while playing it wouldnt want the button shown)... so its most likely that the video itself is resetting the button style on play pause.... you'll have to lookup video format documentation to see what function/event hooks are available to your page/site/code

Comment: `display:none` didn't work either. Using `remove()` on the svg worked perfectly!